# Python - Android logcat output of stdout to textview then save to .txt file error

Tags: android, python, wxpython, logcat

I have the following Python code, it uses Android logcat via stdout to pull the logs off the phone into a wxPython Text field. 
I login to my app, username jack and password Jack@123$ the logcat output stops with an error, it seems to not like the @ or $ symbols:

```
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 76: character maps to <undefined>
```

Or when I try to GetValue() of the text control to save it into a .txt file that is open for writing:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position  204447-204449: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code for the logcat function is as follows

```
def logcat(self):
   params = [toolsDir + "\\adb.exe", "logcat"]
   p = Popen(params, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
   for line in p.stdout:
       #line = line.decode('Latin-1')
       self.progressBox.AppendText(line)

def saveLog(self,e):
    f = open(outDir + '\\' + pkgName + '\\' + pkgName + '_logcat.txt', 'w')
    f.write(self.progressBox.GetValue())
    f.close()
```

What would be the correct way of implementing decoding for these symbols using stdout.
Thanks

Comment: I have got a bit further by using the following,   `for line in p.stdout:
                linedec=line.decode('utf-8')
                self.progressBox.AppendText(linedec)`   however I am still stuck when writing to a file.  
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\uae08' in position 107257: character m
aps to <undefined>`  despite decoding before writing to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
Answer is as follows, I had to decode('utf-8') from stdout into a textbox, but then encode('utf-8') when writing to a file.

```
    for line in p.stdout:
        self.progressBox.AppendText(line.decode('utf-8'))


    f.write(self.progressBox.GetValue().encode('utf-8'))
```